# Spring Boot Linux service Log File

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, jar

I have a spring boot uber/fat jar which is set up as a linux service and started using the below command

```
systemctl start servicename
```

The spring boot jar has the below log file configuration

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="logs/spring.log"/>

    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>

    <property name="SPECIAL_FILE_NAME" value="special"/>
    <appender name="SPECIAL_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-10.10thread] %-5level %30.30logger{29}:%-4line %msg%n</pattern>
            <charset>utf8</charset>
        </encoder>
        <file>logs/controller.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/controller-%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.org.app.controller" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SPECIAL_FILE"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

My Service is configured like this

```
[Unit]
Description=myapp

[Service]
User=appuser
WorkingDirectory=/home/appuser 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Xmx256m -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=test /home/appuser/myapp.jar 
SuccessExitStatus=143
TimeoutStopSec=10
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, the logs are not generated when the service is started. Any ideas ??

if i use the command in shell the logs get generated

```
/usr/bin/java -Xmx256m -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=test /home/appuser/myapp.jar
```

I even tried adding the below the the service file however no luck.

```
StandardOutput=/home/appuser/logs/log.log
StandardError=/home/appuser/logs/error.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone comes here looking for an answer needs to do this

Create a script file(myapp.sh) and put the contents to start the file there like

```
java -Xmx256m -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=test /home/appuser/myapp.jar
```

Next in your service file remove the java command and put this file reference like this

```
[Unit]
Description=myapp

[Service]
User=appuser
WorkingDirectory=/home/appuser 
ExecStart=/home/appuser/myapp.sh
SuccessExitStatus=143
TimeoutStopSec=10
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Next make sure the script file has the execute permission something like this

```
chmod +x /home/appuser/myapp.sh
```

Thats it, now tart your app and you should see the logs, for my serivce the logs are created at

```
/home/appuser/logs
```